# Tourble submitting desktop app for review "payment details are required before any application can be reviewed"

Tags: software-center

I am trying to submit an app (ubuntu desktop) in the software center through here:

https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/

After filling in all the required fields and clicking the button "Submit for review", I receive the following message:

"Payment details are required before any application can be reviewed"

How could this issue be resolved?

Thank you,

-Nikos

Comment: Give your payment details?

Comment: Where exactly can I do that? There is only one screen called "Your account details" where I can enter personal information. The only field related to payment information on that screen is a PayPal e-mail which is marked as optional. I provided a PayPal e-mail, updated, but still the same issue. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

as stated [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/publish-a-commercial-app/) (step 5), you must provide details of your PayPal account (email), Phone number and Postal address (ZIP code).

Click on Update my account details and then Submit to review.

Remember: The minimum price you can charge is $2.99